# How get get State objects when performing beforeunload in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have this object that I'm trying to save to an session persisted array with the beforeunload event

```
  const { serviceRequest, serviceRequestOriginal, isDirty } = useAppSelector((state) => state.csmRequestDataReducer);

  useEffect(() => {
    
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (event) => {
      console.log('beforeunload:' + isDirty);
      console.log(current(serviceRequest));
      console.log('beforeunload:' + isDirty);
      dispatch(persistRequestTab({ currentSRCurrentState: isDirty ? serviceRequest : null, currentSRPreviousState: isDirty ? serviceRequestOriginal : null }));
      console.log("API call before page reload");
    });
    
  }, []);
```

However the console output shows serviceRequest = null and isDirty = false.

Why is this and can I alter/fix to get these objects/values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I don't know if this is a perfect resolution however it seems to work really well.

When creating the event listener it locks in the initial state objects values, using a reference useRef() will get around this, just make sure to update the reference as state is updated with some more useEffects.

```
  const { serviceRequest, serviceRequestOriginal, isDirty } = useAppSelector((state) => state.csmRequestDataReducer);
  const currentSRRef = useRef<ServiceRequest | null>(serviceRequest);
  const currentSROrigRef = useRef<ServiceRequest | null>(serviceRequestOriginal);
  const currentIsDirtyRef = useRef<boolean>(isDirty);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (event) => {
      console.log('beforeunload:' + currentIsDirtyRef.current);
      dispatch(persistRequestTab({ currentSRCurrentState: currentIsDirtyRef.current ? currentSRRef.current : null, currentSRPreviousState: currentIsDirtyRef.current ? currentSROrigRef.current : null }));
    });
    
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    currentSRRef.current = serviceRequest;
    currentIsDirtyRef.current = isDirty;
  }, [serviceRequest])

  useEffect(() => {
    currentSROrigRef.current = serviceRequestOriginal;
  }, [serviceRequestOriginal])
```